# How to assign a common id based on other columns/id's in R?

Tags: r, algorithm, functional-programming, network-programming

I have a dataframe which looks like this :

```
Sn  id1 id2 id3    
1   abc 123  NA   
2   xyz 111 vvv  
3   qwe 222 vvv    
4   rty  NA  NA    
5   abc  NA  NA    
6   ddd 234  NA   
7   sss 222  NA   
8   aaa  NA  NA
```

Now I want to create a new column 'output' based on following logic :

First level of relationship : All the entities where even a single `id` matches (`NA`'s do not count) must be assigned same `id`.

Second level of relationship : If 2 is connected to 3 and 3 is connected to 7, then 2,3 and 7 all must have same `id`.

Hence the output here would be :

```
Sn  id1 id2 id3 id4    
1   abc 123 NA  100001   
2   xyz 111 vvv 100002  
3   qwe 222 vvv 100002  
4   rty NA  NA  100003    
5   abc NA  NA  100001    
6   ddd 234 NA  100004    
7   sss 222 NA  100002   
8   aaa NA  NA  100005
```

Please let me know what is the easiest way to do this. Any thoughts are welcome.

I am currently thinking of creating a 8*8 matrix which will contain a flag to indicate if there is any match between the two entities(rows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to do tasks like this (with "connected" nodes) using `igraph`. So if we start with your sample data in a copy/paste-friendly data.frame format

```
dd <- data.frame(
    Sn = 1:8, 
    id1 = c("abc", "xyz", "qwe", "rty", "abc", "ddd", "sss", "aaa"), 
    id2 = c(123L, 111L, 222L, NA, NA, 234L, 222L, NA), 
    id3 = c(NA, "vvv", "vvv", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
    stringsAsFactors=F
)
```

Now the first step is to build an edge list connectin all the nodes on a given row

```
el <- rbind(
    setNames(dd[,2:3], c("A","B")),
    setNames(dd[,3:4], c("A","B"))
)
el <- el[complete.cases(el),]    #(ignore NA)
```

And we also need a unique list of all the vertext names

```
vx <- na.omit(unique(unlist(dd[, 2:4])))
```

Now we can create a graph object

```
library(igraph)
gg<-graph.data.frame(el, vertices=vx, directed=F)
plot(gg)
```

[image]

We can then use the `cluster()` function to find the different groups and get a group number for each vertex

```
newid <- data.frame(
    vertex=V(gg)$name, 
    grp=clusters(gg)$membership
)
```

Now, if we want to assign that back to the original data.frame, we really just need to match on the `id1` column.

```
dd$id4 <- newid$grp[match(dd$id1, newid$vertex)]+100000
dd

#   Sn id1 id2  id3    id4
# 1  1 abc 123 <NA> 100001
# 2  2 xyz 111  vvv 100002
# 3  3 qwe 222  vvv 100002
# 4  4 rty  NA <NA> 100003
# 5  5 abc  NA <NA> 100001
# 6  6 ddd 234 <NA> 100004
# 7  7 sss 222 <NA> 100002
# 8  8 aaa  NA <NA> 100005
```

and we get the results you desired.

Comment: Thanks. That really helped. A small addition while building edge list connection.We would want to connect id1 and id3 as well in case there is any NA in the id2 column.
el <- rbind(
  setNames(dd[,2:3], c("A","B")),
  setNames(dd[,3:4], c("A","B")),
  setNames(dd[,c(2,4)], c("A","B"))
)

Comment: I thought about this but I couldn't come up with an example where this was required or produced a different result. Do you have such an example? Do you perhaps have NA in id2 but values in both id1 and id3?

Comment: Correct. There are cases in the real dataset where I have NA in id2 but values in id1 and id3.